# What is root cause for segmentation fault for below linked list program?

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Below is the Program to add a new node to the ascending order linked list.

There was bug in below program which causing `segmentation Fault` I figured out the cause for segmentation Fault using `gdb`.

But i did not get what is `reason` for segmentation Fault. Can anyone tell reason for segmentation Fault.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>

  struct node
 {
     int data ;
     struct node *link ;
 } ;

 void add ( struct node **, int ) ;
 void display ( struct node * ) ;

 int  main( )
{
       struct node *p ;
        p = NULL ;  

    add ( &p, 5 ) ;
    add ( &p, 1 ) ;
    add ( &p, 6 ) ;
    add ( &p, 4 ) ;
    add ( &p, 7 ) ;


    display ( p ) ;

}


void add ( struct node **q, int num )
{
    struct node *r, *temp = *q ;

    r = ( struct node *)  malloc ( sizeof ( struct node ) ) ;
    r -> data = num ;


  if ( *q == NULL || ( *q ) -> data > num )
 {
    *q = r ;
    ( *q ) -> link = temp ;
 }
 else
 {
    while ( temp != NULL )
    {
        if ( temp -> data <= num && ( temp -> link -> data > num || 
                                    temp -> link == NULL ))
        {
            r -> link = temp -> link ;
            temp -> link = r ;
            return ;
        }
        temp = temp -> link ;  
    }
  }
}


void display ( struct node *q )
{
    printf ( "\n" ) ;


    while ( q != NULL )
    {
        printf ( "%d ", q -> data ) ;
       q = q -> link ;
    }
}
```

I changed the order in this line from

```
if ( temp -> data <= num && ( temp -> link -> data > num || temp -> link == NULL ))
//                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

to

```
if ( temp -> data <= num && ( temp -> link == NULL || temp -> link -> data > num  ))
//                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The above changed work like a charm But i dint get reason  behind this changes.

So help me to figure out the reason

**Updated

If short-circuit evalution is real cause then why this below program works

```
      int main()
     {

       int a=10,b=1,c=0;
       int d;
       d = (a && (c || b));

       printf("%d",d);
      getchar();
      }
```

Comment: Did you use any debugger?

Comment: Because boolean operators do "short circuit" evaluation

Comment: ya gdb is used to debug and its stopped @ above changed line

Comment: @pmg in the case int main()
{

 int a=10,b=1,c=0;
 int d;
 d = (a && (c || b));

 printf("%d",d);
 getchar();
}   in that case this program should yield 0 right?

Comment: If `( *q ) -> data > num )` is true then you reassign `*q` to point to your new node, but what happens to the list already pointed to by `*q`?

Comment: You are dereferencing `temp -> link` without checking it for NULL and thus a segfault. In second case, you check it for NULL, and if it is NULL, [dereferencing is not done](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: Also, [don't cast the return of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: The working program you added in your edit works because the expression `c` doesn't dereference a `NULL` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
temp -> link -> data > num || temp -> link == NULL
```

will first evaluate the left hand side of the logical or, and if it's false then the right hand side will be evaluated. That means if `temp->link` is `NULL` then you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you dereference a `NULL` pointer.

What the change does is that it changes the evaluation order of the two sub-expressions in the logical or expression, so it *first* check `temp->link` not being `NULL`, and then dereferences `temp->link`.

Answer (score 1):

When you do like this-

```
if ( temp -> data <= num && ( temp -> link -> data > num || temp -> link == NULL ))
```

In `temp -> link -> data`, If `temp -> link` is equal to or when `temp -> link` is `NULL` means this expression becomes `NULL -> data`. you are trying to dereferencing NULL. so you will get `segmentation fault`.

```
if ( temp -> data <= num && ( temp -> link == NULL || temp -> link -> data > num  ))
```

In this case you won't get segmentation fault. because when `temp -> link` is `NULL` condition becomes true, Program execution enters into the body of the loop. So you wont get `segmentation fault` here. But when `temp -> link` is not `NULL` then it will dereference it.

Answer (score 0):

In the second version of the if statement, [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) will make sure that `temp->link` is never dereferenced.